# Does Star-Lord ever go back to earth?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1

In the Marvel Cinematic Universe, did Star-Lord ever go back to earth, following his capture by the Ravagers?

He had his own space ship, *The Milano*, so he is presumably capable of returning to earth.

If he doesn't go back, is there any reason why he's prevented from or chooses not to, even for a visit?

In the comics, everyone was prevented from interfering with earth, but I don't think there's any reference to this decree in the film.

Comment: Doubtful that he really wants to anyways. His mother seemed to be the only person he really cared about prior to the events of GotG1.

Comment: It would explain the presence of the cassette player in his ship

Comment: @phantom42 What about his grandfather?

Comment: It's possible, but the impression I got from the scene was that his mother was his only real connection.

Comment: @RogueJedi my interpretation of that opening scene was that Peter was seen by his entire family as an outsider, maybe because of his age? His temperment? But that Peter could only be consoled or understood by his mother. And his 'immaculate' conception might've only further distanced Peter from the rest of his family.

Comment: @dasMetzger The immaculate conception refers to Mary's birth. You're thinking of the virgin birth. But a good point, none the less.

Comment: No one implies that Peter was a virgin birth either, just that his father is not Terran or anything else the Xandarians were familiar with.

Comment: @phantom42 I'm assuming his expanded-family doesn't know about his father.

Comment: Imagine if he had: https://youtu.be/d0K436vUM4w?t=3m17s

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This certainly is not canonical and certainly not definitive, but there are few clues as to why I think he has been back to earth.

- Has a wood paneled tape player that is not the one he was listeniing too when he was abducted.
- References Pulp Fiction and Jackson Pollack
- Peter's Ship has other earth things that are too many to keep in a backpack.

However, it certainly is not beyond the realm that Yondu collected those items with his trip to earth and gave them to Peter. Or that Peter could have picked up some sort of broad cast that showed him the culture over the last 20 years.

Comment: When does Peter Quill reference *Pulp Fiction*?

Comment: @DrRDizzle , I am assuming when he talks about the "shinny new suitcase" in this clip, that he is referring to Pulp Fiction as the other statements he say in that same line describing the orb also reference difference movies.("Ark of the Covenant" and "Maltese Falcon-esque vibe") Go to 1:37, http://themoviebox.net/5246